# Angularjs: parent and child scope

Tags: angularjs

**point 1**

i just do not understand why i could not access child controller property this way `{{$scope.parentcities}}`. but if i write like this way `{{parentcities}}` then it is working. so why we can not write `$scope dot and then property name`

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
       {{$parent.cities}}
       <br>
       {{$scope.parentcities}}
    </div>
</div>

function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.parentcities = $scope.$parent.cities;
}
```

### **point 2**

need some guide line what kind of syntax it is ChildCtrl as vm ?

when we need to mention controller in html ChildCtrl as vm like this way ?

does it carry any special meaning?

looking for some guidance. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are going to use `Ctrl as c` syntax please assign values to `this` variable

```js
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  this.parentcities = $scope.$parent.cities;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
    {{$parent.cities}}
    <hr>
    {{vm.parentcities}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point of $scope is that you don't need to write it when you bind values to the view. So `$scope.supervalue = 'Hallo'` will be accessed in the view like this `{{ supervalue }}`. That's it.

`$parent`is a keyword from the Angular framework to [reference the parent scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

The controllerAs syntax is made to get rid of the $scope keyword alltogether. So inside the controller, you can write it like this:

```
var self = this;
self.supervariable = 'Hallo';
```

In your config for this route, you specifiy `controllerAs: 'vm'`. So you can access your values in the view via `{{ vm.supervariable }}`. [Have a look here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) to learn all about it.

But, it seems like you should do some groundwork first and learn about the basic Angular mechanism before you dive into `controllerAs`, which has some tricky parts to it later on.

Comment: see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/of8m9ep1/1/ i use `{{vm.parentcities}}` but does not work. would you give your suggestion why it is not working.

Comment: I've updated it. Take care of your syntax. When you are using controllerAs, you need to use var self = this. http://jsfiddle.net/of8m9ep1/4/ So, instead of just copying stuff from the internet, do some groundwork and learn it properly.